# How to get store in Next.js using Redux Toolkit?

Tags: typescript, redux, next.js, jestjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make integration testing of my application using Jest. For this case I need to render component to reach any of queries. But for rendering component I need to wrap it in `Porvider` to get access for component to the store. Like this

```
//__tests__/Calculator.test.tsx

import { Calculator } from "@/components";
import { cleanup, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

afterEach(cleanup);

it("Check Calculator", () => {
  const CalculatorTest: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (
      <Provider store={}>
        <Calculator></Calculator>
      </Provider>
    );
  };
  const { queryAllByTestId } = render(<CalculatorTest />);
  expect(queryAllByTestId("calc-test")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

But the problem is I'm using **Next.js**. Because of this I have to use Next-redux-wrapper (link: https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper ). As I understand this is made to synchronize store on client side and server side. Anyway for this purpose I use wrapper so to provide store to the whole project I use such a code.
Here's my `_app.tsx`. The syntax of this code was taken from wrapper documentation.

```
//pages/_app.tsx

const MyApp: FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
      </Head>
      <Component {...props.pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

Therefore, as you can see, I only get a store in this line of code.

```
 const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest);
```

And Ihardly can understand how it happens and how to reach store in my test file.

Next, I don't import MyApp anywhere. I think it makes the **Next.js** engine somewhere. I just create an `index.tsx` file in the `pages` folder, in which I call the components. Here's what it looks like.

```
//pages/index.tsx

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <div className="root d-flex justify-content-center">
      <History />
      <Calculator />
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps =
  wrapper.getServerSideProps((store) => async ({ params }) => {
    await store.dispatch(fetchHistory());
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  });
export default Index;
```

For clarity of understanding, I also want to show how my store looks like.

```
//redux/store.ts

const makeStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: {
      history: calculatorHistoryReducer,
    },

    devTools: true,
  });

const store = makeStore();

export type RootStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type RootState = ReturnType<RootStore["getState"]>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
export const useAppDispatch: () => typeof store.dispatch = useDispatch;

export const wrapper = createWrapper<RootStore>(makeStore);
```

Could you please tell me how to properly render a component in Jest dom so that I could test it and access different queries?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was so easy, I don't know why didn't it come at once.
So as you may notice I have a store but don't export it cause I export Wrapper. So for testing and any other tasks where you need store you can just easily export it.

```
//redux/store.ts

const makeStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: {
      history: calculatorHistoryReducer,
    },

    devTools: true,
  });

export const store = makeStore(); // HERE!

export type RootStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type RootState = ReturnType<RootStore["getState"]>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
export const useAppDispatch: () => typeof store.dispatch = useDispatch;

export const wrapper = createWrapper<RootStore>(makeStore);
```

And after that you may use it for Provider in Jest render Dom. Like this.

```
import { store } from "../../redux/store";

afterEach(cleanup);

it("Check Calculator", () => {
  const CalculatorTest: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Calculator />
      </Provider>
    );
  };
  const { queryAllByTestId } = render(<CalculatorTest />);
  expect(queryAllByTestId("calc-test")).toBeTruthy();
});
```